# Connecting to AWS Neptune with Gremlin GraphFactory

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

The examples on the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-java.html) show how to connect to AWS Neptune using Gremlin as follows:

```
Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.build();
builder.addContactPoint("your-neptune-endpoint");
builder.port(8182);
builder.enableSsl(true);
builder.keyCertChainFile("SFSRootCAG2.pem");

Cluster cluster = builder.create();

GraphTraversalSource g = EmptyGraph.instance().traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));
```

However, my current code to connect to a generic Gremlin graph looks like:

```
Configuration conf = new PropertiesConfiguration(...);
...    //Set configuration
Graph graph = GraphFactory.open(conf);
```

Does anyone know how to use this second approach with a GraphFactory to connect to Neptune? I haven't been able to find any examples anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neptune does not provide a `Graph` instance as Gremlin is executed remotely not locally. `GraphFactory` is really only for situations where you have a `Graph` instance you want to create. There used to be a `RemoteGraph` that allowed for this (though still used in the TinkerPop test suite), but that approach has long since been abandoned and is no longer recommended.

The method for connecting to Remote Gremlin Providers like Neptune that you initially presented is the recommended way to establish the `GraphTraversalSource`. It is worth noting however that as of 3.3.5 the preferred method gets rid of `EmptyGraph` and allows you to instantiate the `GraphTraversalSource` anonymously as follows:

```
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote('conf/remote-graph.properties');
```

There are other overloads for `withRemote()` that should look familiar as well.

Comment: One of the reasons we were using a Graph is that we wanted to read GraphML files (e.g. `graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).reader().batchSize(batchSize).create().readGraph(inputStream, graph);`). Is this possible with a `GraphTraversalSource`?

Comment: it is as of 3.4.0, but that just released today officially and i'm fairly certain Neptune has not adopted the syntax yet. you can see more about the new `g.io()` step here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/reference/#io-step If you need to read a GraphML file to Neptune, I think I would suggest reading it into a TinkerGraph then copying that data to Neptune with a script.